# Having troubles flattening array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reduce an array of objects by converting the inner objects with several properties, to string, and then replace the content of the object with that string, by removing the property with `delete` keyword, and then adding a string property with the same name. For some reason, after I delete some property, my code still runs over it, but now its a string, not an object and the code crashes. For example the next object:

```
    var person={
                id:2, 
                userNames:[{name:"jack1", email:"jack1@ccc.com"}, 
                           {name:"superjack", email:"superjack@bbb.com"}],
                empryProp:"",
                empryArr:[],
                booleanProp:true
               }
```

The end goal is to flat this object to:

```
    var person={
                id:2, 
                userNames:"jack1 jack1@ccc.com; superjack superjack@bbb.com",
                empryProp:"",
                empryArr:[],
                booleanProp:true
               }
```

JS:

```
    function flattenArrOfObjects(arrayOfObj){

    let tmpVa = "";
    let tmpProp = "";

    arrayOfObj.forEach(avatarObj => {
        for(let avatarProp in avatarObj){
            if (avatarProp === "dateCreated" || avatarProp === "dateModified") {
                avatarObj[avatarProp] = new Date(avatarObj[avatarProp]).toLocaleDateString();
                continue;
              }

              if(avatarObj[avatarProp].length === 0 ||
                 avatarObj[avatarProp] === "" || 
                 avatarObj[avatarProp] === 0 || 
                 typeof(avatarObj[avatarProp])=== "boolean" ||
                 typeof avatarObj[avatarProp] === "number"){
                  continue;
              }else{
                //lets decide what avatarProp is. single string? array of strings? array of objects?
                if(Array.isArray(avatarObj[avatarProp])){
                    //its an array. strings or objects?
                    avatarObj[avatarProp].forEach(element => {
                        if(typeof(element) === "object"){
                            //its an array of objects
                            avatarObj[avatarProp].forEach(obj => {
                                tmpProp = avatarProp;
                                for(let avatarProp in obj){
                                    if(avatarProp === "dateCreated" || avatarProp === "dateModified" || avatarProp === "id"){
                                        continue;
                                    }else{
                                        tmpVa += avatarProp + " - " + obj[avatarProp]+"; ";
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            delete avatarObj[tmpProp];
                            avatarObj[tmpProp] = tmpVa;
                            tmpProp = "";
                            tmpVa = "";
                        }else{
                            //array of strings
                            avatarObj[avatarProp] = avatarObj[avatarProp].join("; ");
                        }
                    });
                }
              }
        }
    });

    return arrayOfObj;
  }
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  function flattenArrOfObjects(arrayOfObj) {

    let tmpVa = "";
    let tmpProp = "";

    arrayOfObj.forEach(avatarObj => {
      for (let avatarProp in avatarObj) {
        if (avatarProp === "dateCreated" || avatarProp === "dateModified") {
          avatarObj[avatarProp] = new Date(avatarObj[avatarProp]).toLocaleDateString();
          continue;
        }

        if (avatarObj[avatarProp].length === 0 ||
          avatarObj[avatarProp] === "" ||
          avatarObj[avatarProp] === 0 ||
          typeof(avatarObj[avatarProp]) === "boolean" ||
          typeof avatarObj[avatarProp] === "number") {
          continue;
        } else {
          //lets decide what avatarProp is. single string? array of strings? array of objects?
          if (Array.isArray(avatarObj[avatarProp])) {
            //its an array. strings or objects?
            avatarObj[avatarProp].forEach(element => {
              if (typeof(element) === "object") {
                //its an array of objects
                avatarObj[avatarProp].forEach(obj => {
                  tmpProp = avatarProp;
                  for (let avatarProp in obj) {
                    if (avatarProp === "dateCreated" || avatarProp === "dateModified" || avatarProp === "id") {
                      continue;
                    } else {
                      tmpVa += avatarProp + " - " + obj[avatarProp] + "; ";
                    }
                  }
                });
                delete avatarObj[tmpProp];
                avatarObj[tmpProp] = tmpVa;
                tmpProp = "";
                tmpVa = "";
              } else {
                //array of strings
                avatarObj[avatarProp] = avatarObj[avatarProp].join("; ");
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });




    return arrayOfObj;
  }

  var personObj = [{
    accounts: [],
    addresses: [{
      country: "spain",
      city: "madrid",
      street: "someStreet",
      number: 44
    }],
    age: 44,
    country: "spain",
    dateCreated: "2019-06-19T16:09:24.73",
    dateModified: "2019-07-15T12:15:34.94",
    description: "some description",
    device: 0,
    education: [{
      school: "saint charles",
      degree: "master",
      id: 3,
      dateCreated: "2019-06-19T16:09:24.73"
    }, {
      school: "saint clair",
      degree: "not finished",
      id: 2,
      dateCreated: "2018-06-19T16:09:24.73"
    }],
    emails: [{
      dateCreated: "2019-06-19T16:09:24.73",
      mail: "mymail@kkk.com"
    }, {
      dateCreated: "2015-06-19T16:09:24.73",
      mail: "dddddd@kkk.com"
    }],
    favorites: [],
    gender: 2,
    id: 23,
    images: [],
    tab: false,
    interests: ["pet cats", "i love to throw eggplants"],
    isActive: true,
    languages: [{
      language: "english",
      isDefault: true
    }, {
      language: "spanish",
      isDefault: false
    }],
    reports: [],
    maritalStatus: 0,
    name: "Sienna",
    names: [{
      name: "Sienna",
      isDefault: true
    }, {
      language: "Marel",
      isDefault: false
    }],
    nicknames: [],
    phoneNumbers: [{
      language: "english",
      isDefault: true
    }, {
      language: "spanish",
      isDefault: false
    }],
    pictureUrl: "/clientapp/images/blanks/p_profile icon_large_dark.png",
    politicalOrientation: "",
    userAgent: "",
    workPlaces: [{
      company: "apple",
      job: "chairman"
    }, {
      company: "intel",
      job: "lab worker"
    }]
  }];
  console.log(flattenArrOfObjects(personObj));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>flat objects</button>
```

Comment: `"message": "TypeError: avatarObj[avatarProp].forEach is not a function",`

Comment: I know. This is exactly what i dont understand why. I'm deleting a property, adding another one and i expect the code to move to the next property and not run again over the same property (it was an object, but now its a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up iterating over all objects and their keys, filtering out un-needed properties and on the other hand creating strings out of those that I do need.

```
function flat(arrayOfExportedObjects) {
    arrayOfExportedObjects.forEach(exportedObj => {
        for (let prop in exportedObj) {
            if (typeof exportedObj[prop] !== "string" && typeof exportedObj[prop] !== "number" && exportedObj[prop].length > 0) {
                if(Array.isArray(exportedObj[prop]) && typeof(exportedObj[prop][0]) === "string"){
                    exportedObj[prop] = exportedObj[prop].join("; ");
                    continue;
                }
                let str="";
                for(let p=0; p < exportedObj[prop].length; p++){
                    for(let property in  exportedObj[prop][p]){
                        if(property === "dateCreated" || property === "dateModified" || property === "id" || property === "isDefault"){
                            continue;
                        }else{
                            str += exportedObj[prop][p][property]+ " ";
                        }
                    }
                    str +="; ";
                }
                exportedObj[prop] = str;
                str="";
            }else{
                if(exportedObj[prop].length === 0 || exportedObj[prop] === "" || !exportedObj[prop]){
                    exportedObj[prop]=" ";
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return arrayOfExportedObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const person = {
    id: 2,
    userNames: [{ name: "jack1", email: "jack1@ccc.com" },
    { name: "superjack", email: "superjack@bbb.com" }],
    empryProp: "",
    empryArr: [],
    booleanProp: true
}

const flatPerson = person =>({
    ...person,
    userNames: person.userNames.map(user => `${user.name} ${user.email}`).join('; ')
})

console.log(flatPerson(person))
```

`flatPerson` is a function which takes a `person` argument and then return an object which is the spread of the original person object `...person` and overrides the `userNames` property, transforming each object into a string: `userNames.map(user =>`${user.name} ${user.email}`)` and transform the final array in a string passing the separator as: `;`

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with this syntax, could you please explain? Also, I need to support the option to convert an array of objects.

Comment: What did you mean by 'I need support the option to convert an array of object'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but this looks like you're only mapping the `user.email` and `user.name`. In my original post I have a much complex `person` object. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @undroid If you click `Run Code Snippet` you'll see exactly what the output is. Your entire object is being mapped, you only see `userName` mentioned explicitly because that's the only property that needs to take a different shape 
(based on the `user.name` and `user.email`). The `...person` portion means *"Get me everything from `person`"*, and then the `userNames:` portion overrides *only* the `userNames` property. The result is a shallow-copy of your original `person`, but with the `userNames` value overridden.

Comment: The snippet is doing exactly what was proposed in the question, is there other use case besides this one?

Comment: How can this be more generic, e.g run over all persons properties and not only select ones. Could you please take a look at the full code I've added? The simple `persono` object was only to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm getting out of work now, when I get home i'll update the answer

Comment: Could you guide me how to iterate over all person's properties to flat them all?